# How to create, update or delete according to values in a collection in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j, I have relationship `IS_SIMILAR` with property `similarity` in database, and I have a collection `collect([node_n, node_m, new_similarity]) AS similarity_table` contains new information. I want to:

1. if relationship `(node_n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR]-(node_m)` **exists** and `[node_n, node_m, new_similarity >= 0.5]` in `similarity_table`, only **UPDATE** the value of `r.similarity` to `new_similarity`
2. if relationship `(node_n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR]-(node_m)` **exists** and `[node_n, node_m, new_similarity < 0.5]` in `similarity_table`, **DELETE** `r` (because node_n and node_m are no longer similar)
3. if relationship `(node_n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR]-(node_m)` **does not exist** and `[node_n, node_m, new_similarity >= 0.5]` in `similarity_table`, **CREATE** `(node_n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR]-(node_m)` with `SET r.similarity = new_similarity`
4. if relationship `(node_n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR]-(node_m)` **does not exist** and `[node_n, node_m, new_similarity < 0.5]` in `similarity_table`, do nothing

With `MERGE` I can handle 1+3+4 (by only processing `new_similarity >= 0.5` part):

```
... # calculate similarity and build n, m, new_similarity list
WITH collect([node_n, node_m, new_similarity]) AS sim_table
WITH [val IN sim_table WHERE val[2] >= 0.5] AS similarity_table
UNWIND similarity_table AS s
WITH s[0] AS n, s[1] AS m, s[2] AS sim
MERGE (n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR_TO]->(m)
SET r.similarity = sim
```

But can I combine all these conditional actions (CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE) in one Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read your question you then you have calculated new similarities and now you want a relationship between `node_n` and `node_m` if and only if `new_similarity > 0.5`.

If so then the easiest thing would be to delete all the existing similarities as this takes care of case 2, filter the pairs of relationships on their `new_similarity` value and then merge the relationships. In Cypher it would look like

```
... # calculate similarity and build n, m, new_similarity list
OPTIONAL MATCH (node_m)-[rel:IS_SIMILAR_TO]->(node_m)
DELETE rel
WITH node_n, node_m, new_similarity // Note that I have removed your collect
WHERE new_similarity > 0.5
MERGE (n)-[r:IS_SIMILAR_TO]->(m)
SET r.similarity = new_similarity
```

Note that you can insert a `WHERE` statement under the `OPTIONAL MATCH` to only match on `IS_SIMILAR_TO` relationships with a similarity below 0.5 if you need to, this is just the shortest and most concise way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! Currently I do this way. Just wondering if the data size is huge, delete all and rewrite/merge all may be a large cost. In fact when I do delete all first, I can directly do CREATE and no need to MERGE.

Comment: You can get around that by adding the  `WHERE` statement under the `OPTIONAL MATCH` as mentioned in the bottom part of the answer, but I would profile it to make sure that it actually adds any improvement